# React Native flex not giving height to component

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

The sections labeled with `Dates`, `Time` are where my the data from my `dates` and `timeSpan` will go. The red area is where my calendar would be placed.

I have been trying to fit `Views` to look like tables, but it has not been working out so well. Here's my code:

```
<ScrollView>
      <View>...</View>
      <View **
          style={{
              marginHorizontal: 10,
              marginTop: 10,
              flex: 1,
              borderColor: Colors.separatorColor,
              borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth}}>
                  <View style={{
                      flex: 1, 
                      flexDirection: 'row', 
                      borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                      borderBottomColor: '#EDEDED'}}>
                          <View style={{1, backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}}/>
                        {
                            dates.map((date, i) => {
                                <View key={i} style={{
                                    flex:1, 
                                    backgroundColor: '#00fff0', 
                                    borderRightColor: '#EDEDED', 
                                    borderRightWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth}}>
                                    <Text>{date}</Text>
                                </View>
                            })
                        }
                        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}}/>
                    </View>
                    {
                        timeSpan.map((time,i) => {
                            <View style={{
                                flex: 1, 
                                flexDirection: 'row', 
                                borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                                borderBottomColor: '#EDEDED'}}>
                                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}}/>
                                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}}/>
                            </View>
                        })
                    }
                </View>
                <View>...</View>
            </ScrollView>
```

The `<View>...</View>` is the code for `Other Stuff` that will just make my question look much longer so I cut it out. I'm trying to make the `<View>`s look like a table which have `dates.length` columns and `timeSpan.length` rows.

The issue right now is that nothing appears on my screen when I give `flex: 1` to my `View` that I marked in the code with `**`. However, if I give it a fixed height such as `height: 260`, then I get one big fat red box instead of seeing many `View`s that would make up my custom calendar.

I have put in static data to `dates` and `timeSpan` and checked by logging that the iterations are done over these arrays so I am confident that the rows and columns are being created but they are not shown on the screen.

How would I resolve this issue which I believe is caused by the `flex` values?

## EDIT:

here's a snack example of my app:

```html
<div data-snack-id="@ohnu93/tenacious-marshmallows" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be good if you provided snack example.

Comment: @ParasKorat What do you mean by snack example??

Comment: @ohnu93 he means Expo Snack, an example project hosted on the web so we can look at the code and try to understand the problem better. Here's the link to it https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: @BrunoEduardo ahh thx!

Comment: @ParasKorat added my snack snippet!